# Email tracking (how many times opened, read and ignored) in ReactJS, Mongo and Dotnet

Tags: .net, mongodb, email, event-tracking

I/My team are trying to make an email marketing website as an internship project. We have been given a task to check if a user to whom a mail has been sent to, has opened the mail and how many times they have opened it. We are using ReactJs as front end, Mongo DB as database and Dotnet (C#) as API.

From my/our searches, we found that using a 1x1 pixel for tracking is a good idea but when we went to find any code snippets or any help as to how to write the code on our server, we were not able to find anything. We also were not able to receive much help from the workplace as the internship was meant to be a self learning project.

So if you guys can help us, we would be really grateful.

We tried to make many thing on our own such as using text block as image but we couldn't get/understand what we were able to or are supposed to do.

In simple terms, we do not know how to write a code on our server which could track where and which user opened the image from our database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to complete this task is with Nodemailer. Then in the htmlbody of the email, you would add the 1-pixel image with a GET request back to your server. In that GET request, you would update the necessary fields in your MongoDB document.

Depending on your mail server you will need to check the port and authentication rules as they can be different per mail server.